# How can I receive results from TableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, search

I have `TableViewController` with titles and `TableViewController` with images.
I create `seachBar` in `TableViewController` with titles and when I searching in `TableViewController` with titles I want to receive results from `TableViewController` with images. How can I do this?

Added the search. But it works only with arrays in this controller. How do I make filters for arrays to another controller?

```
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];
if (_animalInt == 0){
_searchResults = [_Arra filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
else if (_animalInt == 1){
    _searchResults = [_Arra1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
 }
 else if (_animalInt == 2){
    _searchResults = [_Arra2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Doesn't work

```
TableViewController *detailViewController;

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];
if (_animalInt == 0){
_searchResults = [detailViewController.arra7 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
else if (_animalInt == 1){
    _searchResults = [detailViewController.arra18 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
else if (_animalInt == 2){
    _searchResults = [detailViewController.arra20 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: did u getting result in : _searchResults ?  if yes then reload table

Comment: How does this help me to make search through the array from another controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use UISearchDisplayController with UISearchBar.

It's recommended by Apple.

Comment: I use UISearchDisplayController with UISearchBar. But How I do search an array of another controller ?

Comment: you can search it in the same controller by setting UISearchDisplayController's delegate to "self"(the controller).